# Restart a program on Windows every time it is finished

Tags: java, windows, powershell

I have written an indexing program in Java that I need to run "as often as possible" on a Windows machine, i.e.

1. When the program is finished, it should be restarted.
2. When the program runs longer than one hour, it should be killed and restarted.

I thought about writing a Java program that "runs forever", but occasionally, the JVM crashes so that this approach does not seem to be reliable.

I guess that I have to write a batch file or a Powershell script, but actually don't know where to start.

Comment: Services have the option to be restarted automatically on failure. So that's what I'd do: Write a "neverending" program and wrap it in a service. Configre the latter to be autorestarted on error. If that is an option.

Comment: Rerunning indexer process "as often as possible" sounds a bit ...work-intensive. Are you sure this is the best approach? How about a scheduled task to run the indexer on recurring basis?

Comment: The *Windows* way would be to implement a small service that starts, monitors and restarts you app. Here is a detailed article on how to to it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt703436.aspx - Sorry not to be able to write an anwser with that, but link only one are frowned upon, and the content is too large to fit in one single SO answer

Comment: @SergeBallesta: The *real* Windows way would be to use the [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614.aspx). You cannot allot a time limit for services (but you can for scheduled tasks). You can also register to have the application restarted on failure, limit running the task when the computer is idle, and so on.

Comment: @vonPryz To be more precise: The indexer also synchronizes two different kind of repositories. This should be done as often as possible. Depending on the found files, it can run between 2 minutes and half an hour, so that it is difficult to schedule it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Not trying to nitpick, but a framework that doesn't meet the requirements arguably cannot *"do more"*. You cannot install a service and have it automatically terminated after *x* minutes. The task scheduler isn't *"enough"*. It's the correct infrastructure to use (be it implemented as a service or something else is an implementation detail of no relevance).

Comment: @IInspectable: what I mean is that the custom service should be installed once and be always running. It will not do the indexing itself, but only start the java indexing program, kills it is is last too long, and restart it. In that sense it can do all what is required and could to more such as restarting the program more often when it does not last too long or what else.

Comment: @JFMeier Does either of your repositories have notifications that some file has been added or removed? If yes, listen for them and grab the exact file that was changed to sync. If both have notifications, then just listen for events on both sides, and that should do.

Comment: @Vesper One repository is just a file system with a special structure. I probably have to walk through it to find new elements.

Comment: @JFMeier If that file system is on Windows-based OS, you can turn on auditing on object access, and audit "create file" and "delete file" events, and listen for them via Windows event subsystem. However make sure to ignore events that arise when your program writes the file while syncing from the other side.

Comment: @Vesper It is a Windows network drive.

Comment: With network it's a tad harder, because you'll have to audit events on the server side to reduce overhead with transferring event data over the network. In fact, I'd move the second repository to a Windows file system and set up DFS to do the continuous synching by native OS methods. What is the other repository?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it is lot more complicated as in my simplified description. Files are read, analysed and deployed to a Nexus repository, intermediately connecting to an SVN to receive further data to create a pom.xml. But maybe the Windows event subsystem will help me speed up the process of reading, which would be helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to play around with **timer** object, like this:

```
$filepath = 'C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe' #change this to your exe location
$exe = 'calc' #change this to your exe process name

$Timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
$Timer.Interval = 1000 #interval in ms
$Timer.Enabled = $true
$Action = {
    $process = Get-Process $exe
     if ($process)
     {
        if ((New-TimeSpan -Start $process.StartTime -End (Get-Date)) -gt ([timespan]'00.01:00:00')) #this timespan equals to 1 hour
        {
            Get-Process $exe | Stop-Process -Force
        }
     }
     else
     {
        Start-Process -FilePath $filepath
     }
     $process = $null
}
[void](Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Timer -EventName elapsed –SourceIdentifier Timer123456 -Action $Action)
$Timer.Start() #to start timer
#$Timer.Stop() #to stop timer
```

You could then run it in background and it will take a look on a process you want.

Though you need to make sure it is have a unique process name.